# Github - copied repo as Zip - now want to pull changes?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Instead of cloning a repo on github, I simply downloaded it as a zip file.

I have made changes, but now need to pull the latest updates from the original repo.

Can I simply init the local code and go from there?

Suggestions appreciated (and next time I will do it the right way!)

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+zip

Answer (score 1):

You should write down the remote repository URL then issue the following commands:

```
git init
git remote add origin <REPO_URL>
```

Then check by `git status` if you did some changes, and in that case commit or stage them.

Finally, issue `git pull`, ore `git pull --rebase` if you committed something in the previous step.

Comment: Thanks Antonia. The REPO_URL is not mine and it would not be welcome to update. Is the above still valid? What are your suggestions for staying connected to the REPO_URL for pulling changes from this third party codebase, but managing my changes locally (or even in my own remote repo)?